# Decode/crypt/obfuscate partial readable .ini file

Tags: c++, encryption, lua, ini, deobfuscation

I need help with decoding a partial readable .ini file.

Example File:

HEX:

```
0f 27 00 00 01 00 00 00 1f 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
67 02 00 00 02 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 b5 d7 cd bc 
03 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 d0 01 00 00 93 00 00 00 
04 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 4a 01 00 00 03 02 00 00 
05 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 56 49 50 65 6e 5f 64 74 
07 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 1e 00 00 00 
1e 00 00 00 43 6c 6f 73 65 57 6e 64 73 28 74 62 
6c 41 75 74 6f 43 6c 6f 73 65 57 6e 64 73 31 34 
29 3b 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 0b 00 00 00 01 00 
00 00 01 00 00 00 3d f0 00 00 02 00 00 00 0c 00 
00 00 ce ef c6 b7 b2 d6 bf e2 cd bc c6 ac 03 00 
00 00 02 00 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 04 00 00 04 00 
00 00 02 00 00 00 65 00 00 00 7b 00 00 00 07 00 
00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 09 00 00 00 01 00 
00 00 02 00 00 00 14 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00
```

ASCII:

```
................
....J...........
WndTeach........
....˜.........../
...¯...........y
oungteach_d.....
................
...........é€...
.......È·¶¨.....
...k...€........
................
...curre_but_con
firm............
........DestroyG
UIWnd(330);.....
...........
```

The strange thing is that only the alfanumeric values in this ini file are not readable. The file is responsible for the GUI positioning, judging from a similar file that was not encrypted it should be something like this:

```
[WndTeach]
ID=45602         \\Random values as example
Type =3          \\Random values as example
Pos= 181 291     \\Random values as example
Size =10 20      \\Random values as example
BackgroundIndex=youngteach_d
Function = DestroyGUIWnd(330);

[Button1]        \\Guess
Type = 3         //Btn Control
ID   = 24001
Pos  = 2 2
Size = 34 16
BackgroundIndex = curre_but_confirm
```

From what I am guessing, the values for ID,Type,Pos,Size are stored in hex, so they are not readable in ASCII, but the BackgroundIndex and Function values are readable by opening file with a text editor.
I extracted some opcode from the dll responsible for loading gui files but I can't make sense of it:

```
.text:10061A38 loc_10061A38:   ; CODE XREF: CGuiWndImpl::IniToBat(char const *)+CAj
.text:10061A38                 lea     edx, [ebp+var_E8]
.text:10061A3E                 push    offset a_dat    ; ".dat"
.text:10061A43                 push    edx
.text:10061A44                 lea     eax, [ebp+Dest]
.text:10061A4A                 push    offset aSS      ; "%s%s"
.text:10061A4F                 push    eax             ; Dest
.text:10061A50                 call    ds:sprintf
.text:10061A56                 add     esp, 10h
.text:10061A59                 lea     ecx, [ebp+Dest]
.text:10061A5F                 push    9002h
.text:10061A64                 push    ecx
.text:10061A65                 lea     ecx, [ebp+var_20]
.text:10061A68                 call    ??0CFile@@QAE@PBDI@Z ; CFile::CFile(char const *,uint) //fopen function
.text:10061A6D                 lea     ecx, [ebp+var_68]
.text:10061A70                 mov     byte ptr [ebp+var_4], 1
.text:10061A74                 call    sub_100812F0
.text:10061A79                 xor     esi, esi
.text:10061A7B                 mov     [ebp+Args], eax
.text:10061A7E                 test    eax, eax
.text:10061A80                 jle     loc_10061BC9
.text:10061A86
.text:10061A86 loc_10061A86:   ; CODE XREF: CGuiWndImpl::IniToBat(char const *)+283j
.text:10061A86                 push    offset aType    ; "Type"
.text:10061A8B                 push    esi
.text:10061A8C                 lea     ecx, [ebp+var_68]
.text:10061A8F                 call    sub_10081900
.text:10061A94                 mov     ecx, eax
.text:10061A96                 dec     ecx
.text:10061A97                 jz      loc_10061B99
.text:10061A9D                 sub     ecx, 63h
.text:10061AA0                 jz      loc_10061B26
.text:10061AA6                 sub     ecx, 32h
.text:10061AA9                 jz      short loc_10061B11
.text:10061AAB                 push    eax
.text:10061AAC                 call    sub_10063F30
.text:10061AB1                 mov     edi, eax
.text:10061AB3                 add     esp, 4
.text:10061AB6                 test    edi, edi
.text:10061AB8                 jnz     short loc_10061AD1
.text:10061ABF                 push    0A31h           ; Args
.text:10061AC4                 push    offset aBqassertPctrlI ; "ínASSERT(pCtrl) in %d line of %sín"
.text:10061AC9                 call    sub_10080440
.text:10061ACE                 add     esp, 0Ch
.text:10061AD1
.text:10061AD1 loc_10061AD1:   ; CODE XREF: CGuiWndImpl::IniToBat(char const *)+178j
.text:10061AD1                 mov     edx, [edi]
.text:10061AD3                 mov     ecx, edi
.text:10061AD5                 call    dword ptr [edx+0BCh]
.text:10061ADB                 mov     ebx, eax
.text:10061ADD                 mov     eax, [ebp+var_10]
.text:10061AE0                 mov     edx, [eax+40h]
.text:10061AE3                 lea     ecx, [eax+40h]
.text:10061AE6                 lea     eax, [ebp+var_20]
.text:10061AE9                 push    eax
.text:10061AEA                 lea     eax, [ebp+var_68]
.text:10061AED                 push    esi
.text:10061AEE                 push    eax
.text:10061AEF                 call    dword ptr [edx+68h]
.text:10061AF2                 mov     edx, [ebx]
.text:10061AF4                 lea     eax, [ebp+var_20]
.text:10061AF7                 push    eax
.text:10061AF8                 lea     ecx, [ebp+var_68]
.text:10061AFB                 push    esi
.text:10061AFC                 push    ecx
.text:10061AFD                 mov     ecx, ebx
.text:10061AFF                 call    dword ptr [edx+6Ch]
.text:10061B02                 mov     edx, [edi]
.text:10061B04                 mov     ecx, edi
.text:10061B06                 call    dword ptr [edx+10h]
.text:10061B09                 mov     ebx, [ebp+var_10]
.text:10061B0C                 jmp     loc_10061BBD
.text:10061B11 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.text:10061B11
.text:10061B11 loc_10061B11:   ; CODE XREF: CGuiWndImpl::IniToBat(char const *)+169j
.text:10061B11                 lea     eax, [ebp+var_20]
.text:10061B14                 lea     ecx, [ebp+var_68]
.text:10061B17                 push    eax             ; struct CFile *
.text:10061B18                 push    esi             ; int
.text:10061B19                 push    ecx             ; struct CIniFile *
.text:10061B1A                 mov     ecx, ebx        ; this
.text:10061B1C                 call    ?LoadToFileExLayout@CGuiWndImpl@@AAEXAAVCIniFile@@HAAVCFile@@@Z ; CGuiWndImpl::LoadToFileExLayout(CIniFile &,int,CFile &)
.text:10061B21                 jmp     loc_10061BBD
.text:10061B26 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.text:10061B26
.text:10061B26 loc_10061B26:   ; CODE XREF: CGuiWndImpl::IniToBat(char const *)+160j
.text:10061B26                 push    278h            ; unsigned int
.text:10061B2B                 call    ??2@YAPAXI@Z    ; operator new(uint)
.text:10061B30                 add     esp, 4
.text:10061B33                 mov     [ebp+var_24], eax
.text:10061B36                 test    eax, eax
.text:10061B38                 mov     byte ptr [ebp+var_4], 2
.text:10061B3C                 jz      short loc_10061B49
.text:10061B3E                 mov     ecx, eax
.text:10061B40                 call    ??0CGuiWndImpl@@QAE@XZ ; CGuiWndImpl::CGuiWndImpl(void)
.text:10061B45                 mov     edi, eax
.text:10061B47                 jmp     short loc_10061B4B
.text:10061B49 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.text:10061B49
.text:10061B49 loc_10061B49:   ; CODE XREF: CGuiWndImpl::IniToBat(char const *)+1FCj
.text:10061B49                 xor     edi, edi
.text:10061B4B
.text:10061B4B loc_10061B4B:   ; CODE XREF: CGuiWndImpl::IniToBat(char const *)+207j
.text:10061B4B                 test    edi, edi
.text:10061B4D                 mov     byte ptr [ebp+var_4], 1
.text:10061B51                 jnz     short loc_10061B6A
.text:10061B58                 push    0A20h           ; Args
.text:10061B5D                 push    offset aBqassertPwndIn ; "ínASSERT(pWnd) in %d line of %sín"
.text:10061B62                 call    sub_10080440
.text:10061B67                 add     esp, 0Ch
.text:10061B6A
.text:10061B6A loc_10061B6A:   ; CODE XREF: CGuiWndImpl::IniToBat(char const *)+211j
.text:10061B6A                 mov     edx, [ebx+40h]
.text:10061B6D                 lea     eax, [ebp+var_20]
.text:10061B70                 lea     ecx, [ebx+40h]
.text:10061B73                 push    eax
.text:10061B74                 lea     eax, [ebp+var_68]
.text:10061B77                 push    esi
.text:10061B78                 push    eax
.text:10061B79                 call    dword ptr [edx+68h]
.text:10061B7C                 mov     edx, [edi+40h]
.text:10061B7F                 lea     eax, [ebp+var_20]
.text:10061B82                 lea     ecx, [edi+40h]
.text:10061B85                 push    eax
.text:10061B86                 lea     eax, [ebp+var_68]
.text:10061B89                 push    esi
.text:10061B8A                 push    eax
.text:10061B8B                 call    dword ptr [edx+6Ch]
.text:10061B8E                 mov     edx, [edi]
.text:10061B90                 push    1
.text:10061B92                 mov     ecx, edi
.text:10061B94                 call    dword ptr [edx+4]
.text:10061B97                 jmp     short loc_10061BBD
.text:10061B99 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.text:10061B99
.text:10061B99 loc_10061B99:   ; CODE XREF: CGuiWndImpl::IniToBat(char const *)+157j
.text:10061B99                 mov     eax, [ebx+40h]
.text:10061B9C                 lea     edi, [ebx+40h]
.text:10061B9F                 lea     ecx, [ebp+var_20]
.text:10061BA2                 lea     edx, [ebp+var_68]
.text:10061BA5                 push    ecx
.text:10061BA6                 push    esi
.text:10061BA7                 push    edx
.text:10061BA8                 mov     ecx, edi
.text:10061BAA                 call    dword ptr [eax+68h]
.text:10061BAD                 mov     eax, [edi]
.text:10061BAF                 lea     ecx, [ebp+var_20]
.text:10061BB2                 push    ecx
.text:10061BB3                 lea     edx, [ebp+var_68]
.text:10061BB6                 push    esi
.text:10061BB7                 push    edx
.text:10061BB8                 mov     ecx, edi
.text:10061BBA                 call    dword ptr [eax+6Ch]
.text:10061BBD
.text:10061BBD loc_10061BBD:   ; CODE XREF: CGuiWndImpl::IniToBat(char const *)+1CCj
.text:10061BBD                 ; CGuiWndImpl::IniToBat(char const *)+1E1j ...
.text:10061BBD                 mov     eax, [ebp+Args]
.text:10061BC0                 inc     esi
.text:10061BC1                 cmp     esi, eax
.text:10061BC3                 jl      loc_10061A86
.text:10061BC9
.text:10061BC9 loc_10061BC9:   ; CODE XREF: CGuiWndImpl::IniToBat(char const *)+140j
.text:10061BC9                 lea     ecx, [ebp+var_20] ; this
.text:10061BCC                 call    ?Close@CFile@@UAEXXZ ; CFile::Close(void)
.text:10061BD1                 lea     ecx, [ebp+var_20] ; this
.text:10061BD4                 mov     byte ptr [ebp+var_4], 0
.text:10061BD8                 call    ??1CFile@@UAE@XZ ; CFile::~CFile(void)
.text:10061BDD                 lea     ecx, [ebp+var_68]
.text:10061BE0                 mov     [ebp+var_4], 0FFFFFFFFh
.text:10061BE7                 call    sub_100808D0
.text:10061BEC                 mov     ecx, [ebp+var_C]
.text:10061BEF                 pop     edi
.text:10061BF0                 pop     esi
.text:10061BF1                 mov     eax, 1
.text:10061BF6                 pop     ebx
.text:10061BF7                 mov     large fs:0, ecx
.text:10061BFE                 mov     esp, ebp
.text:10061C00                 pop     ebp
.text:10061C01                 retn    4
.text:10061C01 ?IniToBat@CGuiWndImpl@@UAEHPBD@Z endp
```

The client is written in C++ and uses LUA scripts for ingame functions, maybe the decoding too ? 
The game client (Zero Online) uses the same game engine (C3) as Conquer Online.
I tried looking into Conquer .dat decryption, but the difference is that those .dat files are unreadable so I think they have nothing in common.

The official english game server is dead, so I want to add new functionality to the client for use in a private server.

Thank you for your taking your time reading this long post and I hope I can succeed with this project.

Comment: If the code is lost, why bother with these old ini files? Why not write your own code to serialize/deserialize GUI positions?

Comment: There are functional server files. I can run a private server, I  just wanted to ad more features to the client. I just need to find original values.
The alternative is to printscreen and search for coordinates in game window and make .ini for all gui O.O ...
The game engine accepts plain .ini, but if it doesn't find .ini, searches for .dat, if no .dat found to decrypt. it throws an error.